# Webflow: Manipulating a conversation scoped object in an action

Tags: spring-webflow, spring-webflow-2

I'm new to Webflow and am having an issue: I have some form objects which delegate to an underlying conversation scoped object (and thus modifying it when the form is bound on post).  However, subsequent actions don't see the modifications - it appears when binding, the form is manipulating a different instance of the object than the one in the conversation scope.

Here is one of the view states that has this issue:

```
<view-state id="groupAccount" model="groupAccountForm" >
    <on-entry>
        <evaluate expression="enrollmentAction.createApplication()"
               result="conversationScope.application" />
        <evaluate expression="enrollmentAction.createGroupAccountForm(fapplication)"
               result="viewScope.groupAccountForm" />
    </on-entry>
    <transition on="cancel" to="finish"></transition>
    <transition on="continue" to="employee">
        <!-- <evaluate
            expression="groupAccountForm.getApplication()" result="conversationScope.application" /> -->
        <evaluate
            expression="enrollmentAction.save(application)" />
    </transition>
</view-state>
```

On entry, I create my conversation scoped object and then create the form bean passing it. When the page is submitted, the binding works just fine however, the application passed to enrollmentAction.save(..) doesn't have the values from the page.  The commented out line above it solves the issue but there's got to be a better way of handling this.

This is running on Jetty 6.1, it's a prototype so no authenticated user.

Comment: After some more poking around, I realized that if the application was placed in flowScope, it works just fine.  I assume it's because conversationScope isn't always serialized.  From my (limited) understanding of Webflow, I do need to be using conv scope for the application object as I need it visible to subflows.